# Swagger not showing Fluent validation required fields

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, fluentvalidation, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API which uses Newtonsoft JSON.NET for its serialization. I have fluent validations added to my models and added Swagger.

The fluent validations show up on swagger UI when I use Newtonsoft for serialization.

[image]

But I recreated the same project and this time using `System.Text.Json`, then the fluent validations **do not** show up in the Swagger UI:

[image]

Here is the repo using `System.Text.Json`: https://github.com/tnlthanzeel/Inx.Project.Templates

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through few github issues and found out i had to update the `MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation` to the latest beta version (which is `6.0.0-beta.3` at the time of writing this answer)